# While Loop not breaking when it is supposed to

Tags: python, while-loop

```
def NewCard():
  draw_card = input("Would you like to draw a new card? 'hit' or 'pass': ").lower()
  if draw_card == "hit":
    new_card =  cards[random.randint(0, cards_length)]
    player_cards.append(new_card)
    print(f"Your new hand is {player_cards}")
  elif draw_card == "pass":
     playerturn = False
     return playerturn 

while playerturn == True:
  Check_Scores()
  NewCard()
ComputerPlays()
```

What is supposed to happen is that when the user types "pass" the while loop will break moving on to the next code. But what happens is that the loop repeats forever. This whole block is in another bigger function so that is why it is indented

Comment: The `playerturn` you are setting inside your function is a *local variable*, completely unrelated to the global variable being tested in your `while` loop.  Returning it is pointless, since the call to the function isn't doing anything with the return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
playerturn = True

def NewCard():
  global playerturn
  draw_card = input("Would you like to draw a new card? 'hit' or 'pass': ").lower()
  if draw_card == "hit":
    new_card =  cards[random.randint(0, cards_length)]
    player_cards.append(new_card)
    print(f"Your new hand is {player_cards}")
  elif draw_card == "pass":
     playerturn = False
     return playerturn 

while playerturn == True:
  Check_Scores()
  NewCard()
ComputerPlays()
```

You will need to add a `global playerturn` inside your `NewCard()` function for your code to work. This is because the `playerturn = False` line in your `NewCard()` function actually creates a local variable `playerturn` and sets it to `False` within the scope of the function, and it would not affect the value of `playerturn` outside the `NewCard()` function. For more information on python scopes, please read this [article](https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule).

Answer (score 1):

Here the variable `playerturn` in function `NewCard()` is local to the function itself. Either use the global variable `playerturn` or modify your loop as below:

```
while playerturn==True:
    Check_Scores()
    playerturn=NewCard()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `playerturn` variable in the `NewCard` function is local, not global. Try this:

```
while playerturn == True:
  Check_Scores()
  playerturn = NewCard()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def NewCard():
  draw_card = input("Would you like to draw a new card? 'hit' or 'pass': ").lower()
  if draw_card == "hit":
    new_card =  cards[random.randint(0, cards_length)]
    player_cards.append(new_card)
    print(f"Your new hand is {player_cards}")
  elif draw_card == "pass":
     global playerturn
     playerturn = False
 

while playerturn == True:
  Check_Scores()
  NewCard()
ComputerPlays()
```

setting playerturn as a global fixed my issue